# ROS sensor implementation

Tags: ros, sensors, simulation, uav

From this page, there are lots of sensors to be used in ros robots.

http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors

But, I could not install any of them to the robots in my simulations.

For example, I want to install the camera:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-usb-cam
```

I get the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-usb-cam
```

What is the most straightforward way to install any sensor or camera to a robot? What can be the reason of the error I am getting?

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with sensor packages specifically, the error message says that a package by that name wasn't found, which is more an issue with the package manager. Have you successfully installed any ROS package to this environment before?

Comment: Yes I did. Maybe the problem was, the sensor package was not for the simulation environment I was using.(theconstructsim.com) It was for real hardware to be used on ros.

Comment: Has anyone ever used the same simulation environment before with sensors?

Comment: I gave it a try, and yes, it's as you said: the package isn't available in the cloud environment, probably because it would be useless there. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a problem with sensor packages specifically, the error message says that a package by that name wasn't found, which is more of an issue with the package manager.

You can use the following command to list all ROS Kinetic packages available in your package manager:

```
$ apt-cache search ros-kinetic
```

To check whether a specific package is available, enter the full package name, for example:

```
$ apt-cache search ros-kinetic-usb-cam
```

If the package is not available, nothing will be printed.

In your case, since you're using a cloud environment that is exclusively geared towards simulation, probably no sensor packages will be available. That is not a problem, as you don't need them — the Gazebo simulator used in ROS includes plugins to simulate sensors and other hardware components. See [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins) for details.

Comment: I found there are already many sensors implemented on the robot models I am using. No need to add any additional now, but if needed, the link you sent seems to be useful. Thanks again xperroni